# Limit choices for Django admin filter_horizontal interface

Tags: javascript, django

The Django ModelAdmin offers a `filter_horizontal` (or `filter_vertical`) [interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) for many-to-many relations, which allows the user to filter a list of available related objects.

My goal is to limit the set of choices for this interface, dynamically, based on the value of another form field.

This is somewhat similar to [filtering the form field queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany) or using [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) on the server side, but I want to do it dynamically, on the client side.

The implementation is supposed to be generic, because it is re-used on a variety of admin forms.

An example of the `filter_horizontal` interface is shown below (together with a normal select box).

[image: the filter_horizontal interface]

Based on the source for Django's JavaScript filter interface, viz. [SelectFilter2.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js) and [SelectBox.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/SelectBox.js), I came up with the following JavaScript function:

```
function updateOptionsDisplay(fieldId, allowableOptions) {
    // fieldId is the id of the original <select> element, typically 'id_<model field name>'
    // allowableOptions is an array of allowable object id strings
    for (let side of ['_from', '_to']) {
        // window.SelectBox is set in django's SelectBox.js
        for (let option of window.SelectBox.cache[fieldId + side]) {
            // option is an object with value, text, and displayed properties, not an HTMLOptionElement
            // type of option.displayed in django source is int, not boolean, hence the Number()
            option.displayed = Number(allowableOptions.includes(option.value));
        }
        window.SelectBox.redisplay(fieldId + side);
    }
}
```

This function shows existing `<option>` elements if their value is in the `allowableOptions` array, and hides them otherwise.

The content of the `allowableOptions` array is a function of the value of another form element, e.g. another select box, and is obtained using AJAX in some cases, or from template context in other cases.

This seems to work well, and it also "remembers" previously selected choices.

However, I wonder if there may be some unexpected side effects. Also, any comments with respect to the JavaScript itself would be very welcome.

The whole thing is implemented by extending the admin `change_form.html` template, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/javascript/#javascript-customizations-in-the-admin).

Comment: I'm very interested in this solution as a more readily understandable approach than django-autocomplete-light.  Now three years later, are you finding your code to still be compatible with newer Django versions and likely to be workable for the foreseeable future?

Comment: @Ron Due to a change in our data model, we no longer need to use this. It did work for us using Django 3.2, but I cannot say if it would still work in recent versions: that depends on the JavaScript files mentioned above. You could do a `diff` or `blame` on the latest versions of those files and check for recent changes. Or you could just add this function to your admin (temporarily) and see what happens.

Comment: Your post of this code is a huge help. As of Django 4.2 the Javascript is still working. However, figuring out how to listen for input ('Rabbit' in your example) and query the server for data (for 'Eggs') within Django is not straightforward, because they're not using a standard input element but a span with aria roles attached.  See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218817/dynamic-client-side-update-of-drop-down-choices-in-django-admin) for an extensive explanation.